# Временный сайт Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Я занимаюсь создаю сайт на WordPress для папы, но опыта работы с WP не так много и разработка затянется еще на пару месяцев. Но я бы хотел установить на это время уже готовый шаблон, чтобы папа смог залить туда товар и уже начать получать клиентов.

Сам вопрос: Смогу ли я по завершению разработки собственного шаблона спарсить страницы с товаром со старого шаблона и как это сделать? Где почитать про это? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Там есть импорт / экспорт записей, страниц, фото, и товара

Comment: А где можно прочитать про это?

Comment: Не надо, вот не надо начинать знакомство с WordPress с написания собственной темы. (Темы, кстати. Шаблон в WP - совсем другое). Потерянное время и куча ошибок. Берите любую понравившуюся тему из репозитория WordPress и наполняйте сайт содержимым. Если нужны правки темы, делайте это через создание дочерней темы: https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html

Comment: Тебе не придется ничего парсить. Данные которыми папа будет наполнять сайт, будут лежать в базе данных. При создании темы, тебе придется выводить записи в шаблоны темы в любом случае. То есть данные в БД никак не привязаны к теме сайта.